# How to set the classpath in Windows Command Line correctly

Tags: java, windows, command-line, classnotfoundexception

I have made many attempts to enter a command to run a JAR file correctly from the terminal, and I am 100% sure that all the JAR files and such are in the given paths, but I keep getting a ClassDefNotFoundException. Does it have anything to do with the way that I am entering the command?

```
C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" 

-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\Windows64_Libjitsi\lib\native\windows-64"

-cp 

"C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\SimplifiedConnectionProvider.jar;C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\Windows64_Libjitsi" 

Core.PublicService

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jitsi/service/lib
jitsi/LibJitsi
at Core.PublicService.<clinit>(PublicService.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Didn't work. Tried again:

```
C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" -Djava.
library.path="C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\Windows64_Libjitsi\lib\native\windows-64"
-cp C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\SimplifiedConnectionProvider.jar;C:\Users\ANNA\Downl
oads\Windows64_Libjitsi Core.PublicService

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jitsi/service/lib
jitsi/LibJitsi
        at Core.PublicService.<clinit>(PublicService.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Didn't work. Tried again:

```
C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" -Djava.
library.path=C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\Windows64_Libjitsi\lib\native\windows-64 -c
p C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\SimplifiedConnectionProvider.jar;C:\Users\ANNA\Downloa
ds\Windows64_Libjitsi Core.PublicService
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jitsi/service/lib
jitsi/LibJitsi
        at Core.PublicService.<clinit>(PublicService.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi

        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Note that the class "org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.LibJitsi" really is in a JAR file whose real location is in the folder "C:\Users\Anna\Downloads\Windows64_Libjitsi", which is the class path for JAR files that I am attempting to specify on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have add the JAR to the *CLASSPATH*, not the folder which contains this JAR. So the `-cp` argument should something be like this `C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\SimplifiedConnectionProvider.jar;C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\Windows64_Libjitsi\the_name_of_the_JAR.jar`.

Comment: What if I want all the jar files in a folder?

Comment: I want ALL the jar files in folder "C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\Windows64_Libjitsi" but only one jar file whose name is "C:\Users\ANNA\Downloads\SimplifiedConnectionProvider.jar"

Comment: Nevermind, * is wildcard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath